# Oracle: Subtract hours and show milliseconds for a TIMESTAMP(6) column

Tags: oracle

I want to SELECT a TIMESTAMP(6) with milliseconds, but at the same time I need to subtract 3 hours (0.125 of a day) from that TIMESTAMP to convert it to my timezone. So I tried:

```
SELECT To_Char(UTCSCANTIME-0.125,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS LOCALSCANTIME
Outcome: 2018-08-01 19:22:39
```

If I append **"FF"** to show milliseconds:

```
SELECT To_Char(UTCSCANTIME-0.125,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') AS LOCALSCANTIME
Outcome: ORA-01821: date format not recognized
```

However if I keep the **"FF"** but I don't subtract 0.125:

```
SELECT To_Char(UTCSCANTIME,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') AS LOCALSCANTIME
Outcome: 2018-08-01 22:22:39.259000
```

How can I achieve both things?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you subtract 3 hours? I hope it is not due to time zone calculations. Oracle provides native functions for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract a 3 hour `INTERVAL` instead of 0.125.

```
SELECT To_Char(UTCSCANTIME-INTERVAL '3' HOUR,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') AS LOCALSCANTIME
```

Subtracting a number like 0.125 implicitly converts the result to a `DATE`, losing your fractional seconds.

Also, note, there are better ways in Oracle to convert time zones than to add and subtract intervals.